# Pop-up or notification based on changed cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have one live excel, where in one column value is changing continuously. If the value changes more than 50000 then I should get notification for that particular cell.
Like if change in "E5" I would get notification regarding same.

The notification can be anything like message, pop up, if it can store in another column will also do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you put the amount of times, that cell has been changed, into a cell (like "A1" in the following piece of code):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Row = 5 And Target.Column = 5 Then
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + 1
  End If
  If Range("A1").Value = 50000 Then
    MsgBox ("Cell E5 has been changed 50000 times")
    Range("A1").Value = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

The Worksheet_Change event is launched every time something changes in your worksheet. By checking the targer being "E5" (row and column number being 5), you are sure checking the right cell.

In case your question is different ("What to do in case someone puts a value in a cell, larger than 5000"), then the whole thing is even far easier (no need to put anything in cell "A1" to start with), and as far as the code is concerned:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Row = 5 And Target.Column = 5 And Target.Value >= 50000 Then
    MsgBox ("The value you're trying to enter in cell E5 is too large")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot for ur reply, m explaining in details what i required.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur reply, m explaining in details what i required. In a particular cell say E5, value is continuously changing in range from 1-200 every second. If sometime value entered greater than 5000, then we should get notification for that or can we able to store such(>5000) value in excel?